# Python Dictionary scores

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a code block run on Google Colab:

```
scores = {'Lisa': 8, 'Kate': 7, 'David': 9, 'Steven': 10}

name = input('Enter the student"s name: ')
if name in scores:
  print(scores[name])
else:
  print('No info')

new_name = input('Enter the new name: ')
grade = int(input('Enter the new grade: '))
scores[new_name] = grade
print(scores)
```

However,
It says that my code contains this error:
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

How can I fix this bug? Thank you!

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Did you use `input` as a variable somewhere?

Comment: This piece of code ran for me without issues. You definitely have to check other modules.

Comment: This error almost always means you used a built-in function as a variable name earlier in the code. Either `int`, `input`, or `print`.

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-179-1a3f09747ef5> in <module>()
      1 scores = {'Lisa': 8, 'Kate': 7, 'David': 9, 'Steven': 10}
      2 
----> 3 name = input('Enter the student"s name: ')
      4 if name in scores:
      5   print(scores[name])

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: No, I didn't use input anywhere else

Comment: Show the traceback **in the question**, not as comment.